# WCF service and interoperability

Tags: .net, wcf, xsd

I have the following WCF service that I believe can be improved. I need to be able to support Windows and non-Windows clients using SOAP1.1 and SOAP1.2.

My concerns are with the input parameter initdata on the API InitDataRequest and the return parameter of GetData. Currently, we have a development policy that those parameters are constrained to be XML-formatted strings and the client and the server are responsible for Serializing/Deserializing in their respective environments.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAtomDataInterfaceWcf
{
    [OperationContract]
    Guid OpenSession(AtomSessionType sessiontype);

    [OperationContract]
    void CloseSession(Guid sessionid);

    [OperationContract]
    int InitDataRequest(Guid sessionid, string initdata);

    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(Guid sessionid, int count);
}
```

Using SoapUI the SOAP request for InitDataRequest shows the following element for the parameter 'initdata'.

```
<tem:initdata>?</tem:initdata>
```

This bothered our IBM Websphere developers who expected something else. They suggested, without any guidance, I use an XSD to describe the API hence providing more structure for these parameters, but I have not been able to get my head around how to use it.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing inherently non-interoperable about your service contract. I am not sure why you think there is room for improvement unless the contact does not support the business reason which it was built to address.

You can expose the service over soap 1.1 and 1.2 by defining an endpoint for each of basicHttpBinding and wsHttpBinding respectively.

I don't know what you mean by this:

> we have a development policy that those parameters are constrained to
>   be XML-formatted strings

Soap is an xml standard; all non-xml content must be formatted or you end up with bad xml. This is not a development policy so much as a technical constraint.

I also don't understand what the problem is with soapUI initially setting the string value *initdata* to a question mark. Are you concerned that this is in some way not a valid string? You do realise that soapUI just puts the "?" there initially and you can change it to whatever you want right?

Finally, if consumers of your service are saying they need a xsd then you could [host a WSDL endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751951%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and they can just go to that endpoint and download the xsd from there.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my issue described above is proper usage of the KnownType attribute. using it allows me to rewrite my interface like so:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAtomDataInterfaceWcf
{
    [OperationContract]
    int InitDataRequest(Guid sessionid, AtomDataRequest initdata);

    [OperationContract]
    Guid OpenSession(AtomSessionType sessiontype);

    [OperationContract]
    void CloseSession(Guid sessionid);

    [OperationContract]
    AtomDataResponse GetData(Guid sessionid, int count);
}
```

Where AtomDataResponse and AtomDataRequest have the following structure.

```
[KnownType("GetKnownTypes")]
[DataContract]
public class AtomDataRequest
{
    public static Type[] GetKnownTypes()
    {
      // load known types derived from AtomDataRequest and return as Type array
    }
}
```

After these changes my WSDL is now a rich document which allows a consumer to call the API's with well-defined objects instead of XML-formatted strings.